# GUI Anchor property issue

Tags: c#, winforms, anchor

I've got a label control below another control. I've anchored them top,bottom,left,right.
My problem is when resizing the window. When pulling it down to increase it's size, the control above the list simply covers the label below it. 
I've tried creating a panel to add both controls to that panel leaving their anchor property and setting the panel anchor also to top,bottom,left,right but now when resizing the window, it looks weird like this:
[image: label is now staying above the other control]

Do you have any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't anchor the label to the top. Anchor it to just left, right and bottom. When the window is resized, it will move down and stay below the other control.